# Pathfinder Universalist Wizard casting 0 level spells

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can a Universalist Wizard cast spells from all Schools or only from his own? Specifically, 0 Level.

Answer (score 8):

There are typically no restrictions as to what wizard spells can be cast by a [wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard) who receives the [universalist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/universalist) [school](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Arcane-School).

Answer (score 3):

Wizards (as a whole) are capable of casting any spell they can memorize. Even specialist wizards can cast spells from their Restricted schools, it just takes more spell slots to do so. The universalist wizard starts play with all 0-level spells, and can choose three of them to memorize at 1st level. Because a Universalist has no restricted schools, a 1st level Universalist can pick any of the 0 level spells in their book (up to three), and cast those three spells as many times per day as they wish.

Answer (score 1):

Universalist Wizards can cast spells from any school without trouble or without using up additional spell slots. They have no weaknesses nor strengths you get from specializing in schools.

A wizard that chooses to specialize gets an extra spell of his choice that he can prepare daily, a Universalist doesn't get this bonus spell, but doesn't suffer from the spell preparation issues other wizards that do decide to specialize into do.